# Metro UI CSS: How to achieve class="active" effect?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, durandal, metro-ui-css

In bootstrap there is a nice css class 'active' to apply to menu elements to indicate on which page a user is.

I assume it will work the same in metro ui but I was wrong

```
<ul class="app-bar-menu" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
   <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
      <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The above code (uses Durandal's router) does not make menu items stand out, even if I explicitly set the class without these bindings.

Is there a similiar mechanism in Metro UI CSS for appbar or horizontal menu?
If not, how can I achieve it?

**EDIT**
I found out that class="active" successfully works with lower level menu items but what about the top level?

Comment: From the online documentation, it doesn't look like there is an 'active' class for app bar menu items. But maybe you could apply your own css to give the active items some distinguishing visual feature?

Comment: try to do something like that in your css:   .app-bar-menu.li.active{visibility: visible !important; } and try the display:block !important;

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find solution other than to add css override. For app-bar this would be

```
.app-bar-menu > li.active {
    background-color: #005696;
}
```

If you use non-default colors you'll have to do it specifically for your case, e.g. green:

```
.app-bar.green .app-bar-menu > li.active {
    background-color: #128023;
}
```